# SQL datetime from java

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to add a DATETIME value to the SQL database from Java. Actually I load the java.sql.Date object to an object array and then load the value into the prepared statement from the array.

This is my code:

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
java.sql.Date timestamp = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
values[0] = timestamp;
```

This is the exception that I am getting when I run the code:

```
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'UPDATE_DATE'.
Stack trace:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'UPDATE_DATE'.
```

UPDATE_DATE is the column name in the table. Kindly help me out in this.

**EDIT :** This is the query:

```
INSERT INTO EXAMPLETABLE VALUES UPDATE_DATE=?,CONT_STATUS_NEW_ID=?,CONT_STATUS_DESC=?,LOCATION_ID=?,READ_STATUS=?,CONT_TYPE_ID=?,CONT_TYPE_DESC=?,CONT_ID=?
```

This is where the exception is thrown:

```
((PreparedStatementDataTarget) insertTarget).executeUpdate(values,arguments);
```

Actually you can't get anything out of the execute statement since it implements a lot of classes and custom methods. If there is anything wrong , then it should be in the logic which I use to add the date to the Object array (values) .

Comment: Show us the line where it is throwing the exception. Show your update query.

Comment: @codeaholicguy added query!

Comment: @PrerakSola added prepared statment part and query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing insert and update syntax. You should either use

```
INSERT INTO tableName [(column list)] VALUES (values list)
```

Or

```
UPDATE tableName
SET column = value 
[, column = value]
[WHERE condition]
```

**Note #1:** square brackets mean the part inside is optional.
**Note #2:** column list stands for column names delimited by a comma, values list stands for values delimited by a comma.

Comment: That is not UPDATE . It is UPDATE_DATE=? .. It is one of the columns.

Comment: Do you want to insert a new record or update vlaues in an existing one?

Comment: Then use the correct insert syntax: `insert into tableName (column1, column2) values (?,?)`

Comment: Yup that was the issue . Thanks.